# Iterating over a dictionary values with Nancy and the SSVE

Tags: c#, nancy

I have a viewmodel class which has a property `Dictionary<string,List<string>> FormErrors`. In the SSVE template I'd like to list any error messages

```
<ul>
    @Each.FormErrors["Name"]
    <li>@!Current</li>
    @EndEach
</ul>
```

This doesn't work because it does not appear to like the array indexing.

- How do I access the list of strings for an input to output?
- How do I check if there are any error messages in the first place?